# Weird MySQL behavior with COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this very weird problem with MySQL database.

To simplify the query let's just say that I am calling this query to get profiles matching users settings:

```
SELECT u.*, floor(datediff(now(), u.birth_date) / 365) as age 
FROM users_wr u 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.id = u.city_id 
WHERE u.id != 1 and c.country_id = 71
HAVING age >= 20 AND age <= 25
```

This query now returns set of 3 rows (which is correct). However, when I want to get number of rows like this:

```
SELECT count(*), floor(datediff(now(), u.birth_date) / 365) as age 
FROM users_wr u 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.id = u.city_id 
WHERE u.id != 1 and c.country_id = 71
HAVING age >= 20 AND age <= 25
LIMIT 1
```

then in another case it should return 4, but instead it kept returning 5 and in this case, when it should return 3 it's returning NULL.

I don't know what is that supposed to mean. I am no beginner in sql and this is really bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT count(*), floor(datediff(now(), u.birth_date) / 365) as age 
FROM users_wr u 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.id = u.city_id 
WHERE u.id != 1 and c.country_id = 71
GROUP BY floor(datediff(now(), u.birth_date) / 365)
-- HAVING age >= 20 AND age <= 25
-- LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can't use group by, because that would count every age just once, there can be lot of users with same age.

Comment: @kudlajz: What are you talking about? This is exactly what you need! Did you even try it? If this doesn't work for you then your question is unclear. Please post some example input and output to demonstrate what you are looking for. You might find the website http://sqlfiddle.com useful.

Comment: If you don't use `GROUP BY`, you will certainly have one result on your result list.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL queries are weird, because you are using a (mis)feature of MySQL called Hidden Columns.  In any other database, these queries would be syntax violations, because you have both aggregation functions and non-aggregated columns in the `select` with no `group by`.  This is bad habit.

In the first case, you are getting call rows that match the conditions, because there is no aggregation.

In the second case, you the query returns only *1* row, even without the `limit`.  You get the overall count and a random age that satisfies the `where` and `having` conditions.

The query that you want is:

```
select count(*)
from (SELECT u.*, floor(datediff(now(), u.birth_date) / 365) as age 
      FROM users_wr u LEFT JOIN
           cities c ON c.id = u.city_id 
      WHERE u.id != 1 and c.country_id = 71
     ) t
where age >= 20 AND age <= 25
```

This should return one row with a count of the users meeting all the conditions.